# Android detect other process writing to file

Tags: android, file, locking, file-in-use

My Android app uses a file that the user downloads, using a Web browser.

(Yes, I know that there are ways that an Android app can download a file itself, without sending the user to a Web browser.  I cannot do that in this app, because the file is hosted on Microsoft's OneDrive cloud storage.  And, yes, I know that there is a OneDrive API that can do that, but my understanding is that the user would need to know my OneDrive password before the API could download files.)

I would like to prevent my app from attempting to open a file while the browser is still downloading it.

I tried getting a write lock on the file, using FileChannel.tryLock(), but this granted a lock even while the browser was still downloading the file.  (Apparently locking is voluntary.)

Any other ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: And your code please?

Comment: You could use DropBox. No API is needed to download a file from a public shared folder. I did this in the past by simply using a normal HTTP file download (no WebView at all). See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Comment: Thanks for the comment about DropBox.  It turns out that I am taking advantage of the hugely larger free storage space on OneDrive.